# Invalid cast exception is raised when insert is performed into column of type SYSTIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE with default value

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

Could you please assist with next: 
I have a table with column of type SYSTIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE and with default value - SYSTIMESTAMP. I use Entity Framework 5 database first. When I try to insert entity in this table I get an exception. The exception message is “A store-generated value of type 'System.DateTime' could not be converted to a value of type 'System.DateTimeOffset' required for member 'INSERT_DATE' of type 'Model.SAMPLE'.”. The inner  exception message is: “Invalid cast from 'System.DateTime' to 'System.DateTimeOffset'.”
I use ODAC 12.1012 unmanaged driver.
How should I solve this problem?
Sample table script:

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST"."SAMPLE" 
  ( "ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "INSERT_DATE" TIMESTAMP (6) WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT systimestamp, 
    "TEXT_COLUMN" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    CONSTRAINT "SAMPLE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
 USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
 STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
 TABLESPACE "SYSTEM"  ENABLE
  ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
 PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
 STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
 TABLESPACE "SYSTEM" ;
```

edmx file content:

```
 <edmx:Runtime>
    <!-- SSDL content -->
    <edmx:StorageModels>
      <Schema Namespace="Model.Store" Provider="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" ProviderManifestToken="11.2" Alias="Self" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" xmlns:customannotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2013/11/edm/customannotation" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl">
        <EntityType Name="SAMPLE">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="ID" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="ID" Type="number" Precision="38" Scale="0" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
          <Property Name="INSERT_DATE" Type="timestamp with time zone" Precision="6" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
          <Property Name="TEXT_COLUMN" Type="varchar2" MaxLength="200" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityContainer Name="ModelStoreContainer">
          <EntitySet Name="SAMPLE" EntityType="Self.SAMPLE" Schema="TEST" store:Type="Tables" />
        </EntityContainer>
      </Schema>
    </edmx:StorageModels>
    <!-- CSDL content -->
    <edmx:ConceptualModels>
      <Schema Namespace="Model" Alias="Self" annotation:UseStrongSpatialTypes="false" xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" xmlns:customannotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2013/11/edm/customannotation" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
        <EntityContainer Name="vm2" annotation:LazyLoadingEnabled="true">
          <EntitySet Name="SAMPLE" EntityType="Model.SAMPLE" />
        </EntityContainer>
        <EntityType Name="SAMPLE">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="ID" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="ID" Type="Decimal" Nullable="false" Precision="38" Scale="0" annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
          <Property Name="INSERT_DATE" Type="DateTimeOffset" Precision="9" annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
          <Property Name="TEXT_COLUMN" Type="String" MaxLength="200" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" />
        </EntityType>
      </Schema>
    </edmx:ConceptualModels>
    <!-- C-S mapping content -->
    <edmx:Mappings>
      <Mapping Space="C-S" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/mapping/cs">
        <EntityContainerMapping StorageEntityContainer="ModelStoreContainer" CdmEntityContainer="vm2">
          <EntitySetMapping Name="SAMPLE">
            <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="Model.SAMPLE">
              <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="SAMPLE">
                <ScalarProperty Name="TEXT_COLUMN" ColumnName="TEXT_COLUMN" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="INSERT_DATE" ColumnName="INSERT_DATE" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="ID" ColumnName="ID" />
              </MappingFragment>
            </EntityTypeMapping>
          </EntitySetMapping>
        </EntityContainerMapping>
      </Mapping>
    </edmx:Mappings>
  </edmx:Runtime>
```

Thanks in advance!